# How to create a bridge from a wifi laptop?

Tags: network-bridge

I got a laptop on ubuntu connected to my router via WIFI.
I'd like to connect that laptop using an RJ45 cable to my Hi-Fi soundsystem (It doesn't support wireless)
I'm new to Linux so i'm not sure what kind of bridge I need or even how to do it .

Comment: not bridging... your laptop should act as a router. i dont see a grafical way to achieve this with the network-manager in ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer being an IP router over being a network level switch? Configuration seems easier being a bridge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found!
[image]

The graphical program that shows the feature you need is

`nm-connection-editor`

Launch it from a terminal window.

When it opens, select the wired connection item, clicking the edit button (the cog). In that menu, switch to the IPv4 tab, and select the method: 'shared to other computers', save everything and connect your cable if you haven't already.

That's all

Comment: I can confirm this works, I have a Cisco VOIP phone that's ethernet only (no wifi). Using a Linux laptop (which has both wifi and a USB ethernet dongle) and NetworkManager's GUI like in the above example I was able to 'bridge' it to the wifi network

Comment: @happyskeptic the thing is that if you try this with a wlan connection you get crazy. It seems to only allow Bridging Ethernet as slaves, not wlan