# Can I bridge (same subnet) my wifi (hotspot, not client) to wired LAN using NetworkManager?

Tags: networking, network-manager, router, hot-spot

Setup: I have an Ubuntu box with 2 wired ports (WAN and LAN) and WiFi.

My goal is simple:

I just want the box to behave as a firewall/router (with NAT) from the WAN to the LAN+WiFi, where the latter two are on the same subnet (bridged).  (The box will be doing other things too, and for that and various other reasons I'm not interested in using an off-the-shelf router.)

Using NetworkManager, I can currently set up the LAN as Shared, and the WiFi as a Hotspot, and use UFW for the firewall config, and it basically works (I can connect other devices via LAN or WiFi and get out to the WAN via NAT), but:

- I end up with two separate subnets (so, e.g., my laptop's IP has to change when I switch from LAN to WiFi) and
- The two subnets are also *NATted* to each other, so that if I, say, ssh from a WiFi machine to a LAN machine, the connection appears to be coming from the router box in question rather than from the WiFi machine directly.

For various reasons both of these behaviors are problematic for me (lots of devices on my LAN/WiFi that want to talk to each other freely to and from known and fixed IP addys; currently assigned via host lines in NetworkManager's special dnsmasq config...).

So my main question is how to fix the first problem:  Given that the WiFi hotspot setup is basically all working exactly the way I need, is there a way (with, or in cooperation with, NetworkManager) I can just bridge my LAN onto the same subnet as the hotspot (so that it uses the same dnsmasq instance and NAT to WAN and all of that, but local routing only within the subnet including between the LAN and WiFi)?

Fixing the first problem would, I assume, fix the second, but if the first is unsolvable (with NetworkManager) then a solution for the second alone would be welcome--i.e., how to just get my LAN and WiFi to route directly rather than through NAT, while still using NAT if they go out to the WAN.

Lastly, I'm happy to dump NetworkManager since once configured it should be a very static setup, but as I headed down that path it got ugly fast. Seemed like I needed at least: networkd + hostapd + wpasupplicant + dnsmasq + resolved + nftables + brctl + ?? and the config and interplay between all of these is tricky...  I could probably figure it all out eventually but was hoping there's a simpler way that would require less research and fiddling.  That said, any advice on any approach welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a bridge from a wifi laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037704/how-to-create-a-bridge-from-a-wifi-laptop)

Comment: No, that's what I'm doing already.